# Bazel Build Multiple Targets at Once

Tags: bazel, bazel-rules

I want a Bazel rule that is able to build multiple targets at once. So basically something like this:

```
build_all(
  name = "build_all",
  targets = [
    "//services/service1:build",
    "//services/service2:build",
    "//services/service3:build",
  ]
)
```

So I would just run

```
bazel build //:build_all
```

to build all my services with one simple command (and the same for testing). But I couldn't find any current solutions.

Is there a way to achieve this?

Comment: I googled and found this. Maybe it helps: https://github.com/atlassian/bazel-tools/tree/master/multirun

Comment: Yeah, I've tried it a few minutes ago, but it seems only to work for "runnable" targets. Tests and builds gave me an error. But maybe you can prove me wrong :)

Comment: You should set your services as dependencies of build_all.  Generally, "data" is the most flexible attribute for doing that.  But also know that bazel build //... will build everything and bazel build //services/... will build everything under services.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

It would appear that [`filegroup`](https://docs.bazel.build/versions/master/be/general.html#filegroup) would be a ready made rule that could be abused for the purpose:

```
filegroup(
  name = "build_all",
  srcs = [
    "//services/service1:build",
    "//services/service2:build",
    "//services/service3:build",
  ]
)
```

It otherwise allows you to give a collective name to bunch of files (labels) to be passed conveniently along, but seems to work just as well as a summary target to use on the command line.

Comment: This does not work for me when py_binary rules are listed in srcs. It will silently not rebuild them when their sources are updated. So then I need to go back and call bazel build directly on the py_binary rules.

Comment: What if I have to pass arguments for the build targets?  ex: "bazel build //services/service1:build -- -arg1 -arg2"

Answer (score 3):

If you only want a subset of the build targets the other answers are probably better, but you could also try `bazel build :all` and `bazel test :all`

Comment: This also works with a specific package, see the [Bazel docs](https://bazel.build/run/build#specifying-build-targets) for all scenarios.

Answer (score 2):

Because I was trying to deploy multiple Kubernetes configurations I ended up using [Multi-Object Actions](https://github.com/bazelbuild/rules_k8s#multi-object-actions) for [rules_k8s](https://github.com/bazelbuild/rules_k8s) which then looks like:

```
load("@io_bazel_rules_k8s//k8s:objects.bzl", "k8s_objects")

k8s_objects(
   name = "deployments",
   objects = [
      "//services/service1:build",
      "//services/service2:build",
      "//services/service3:build",
   ]
)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also use `--build_tag_filters` to selectively build multiple targets with a given tags.

EDIT:
`--build_tag_filters` is using OR logic. If you want to build target that satisfy multiple tags, I would suggest you to query it first, and then build the resulting target.

e.g.

```
QUERY="attr(tags, 'tag1', attr(tags, 'tag2', ...))"
BUILD_TARGETS=$(bazel query "$QUERY")
bazel build "$BUILD_TARGETS"
```

Answer (score 0):

The suggestion to use a file group rule as a build-in rule to collect a bunch of dependencies works well if the dependencies are single files (like a cc_binary), but will not trigger creation and collection of auxiliary runfiles (like the labels under "data" in a py_binary) needed for some types of targets.

If you do want to build multiple targets at once, including their runfiles, the [sh_binary](https://bazel.build/reference/be/shell) built in rule with a simple no-opt script is also quite flexible, and you can specify an arbitrary list of targets in its data attribute. These targets will be considered runnable inputs to the sh_binary, and thus will trigger creation of the indirect targets themselves as well as all of their supplementary runtime data.